# Linq To Sql order by Region

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

This is my Linq To Sql Query

```
List<mProjectView> GridView = db.Projects.Where(x => true)
    .Select(x => new mProjectView
    {
        Name = x.Name,
        Code = x.Code,
        Region = db.Locations.Where(y => y.ID == x.RegionID).FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Province = db.Locations.Where(y => y.ID == x.ProvinceID).FirstOrDefault().Name,
        District = db.Locations.Where(y => y.ID == x.DistrictID).FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Id = x.ID,
        Scheme = db.ProjectSizes.Where(y => y.ID == x.ProjectSizeIDOnSubmission)
            .FirstOrDefault().Name,
        Status = x.InitialVisitOutcome
    })
    .OrderBy(db.Locations.Where(y => y.ID == db.Projects.Where(x => x.RegionID))
        .FirstOrDefault().Name)
    .ToList();

gvProjectSearch.DataSource = GridView;
Session["GridData"] = GridView;
gvProjectSearch.DataBind();
```

in the end i wants to ordery by region in my gridview to show but it give me error and i am stuck in it can you please tell me how to solved this.

Comment: What was the error? Post it along with the question.

Comment: you can get rid of that `.Where(x => true)`...why is that there?

Comment: Also, `.FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if no elements exist that meet the criteria, so calling `.Name` could throw a `NullReferenceException`

Comment: Input for the OrderBy is the mProjectView object which is the result of Select query, which doesn't have locations, as you have created Region, Province and District using db.Locations